# Scala SBT custom lib managed path

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible set custom "lib_managed" path in build.sbt? I would want that command update the puts jar files to the my web folder  web/WEB-INF/lib. If sbt does not allows setup custom folder(google finds nothing), what i must add to the build.sbt to copy files from lib_managet folder to my web/.../lib folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom lib managed path"? Do you have any and want it change? What's the current directory you want to change? What do you want to achieve? I'm thinking about `unmanagedBase`, but am still unsure what you're after and need more guidance.

Comment: I want to change path lib_managet to my custom path web/WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lib_managed` is only a build-local cache and it contains jars for all configurations, such as `Test` and `Compile`.  It is not appropriate to list its contents and use it as a classpath.  There may be duplicates or libraries that shouldn't be on the classpath of interest.