# Can minor version update be used to minor update transitive dependencies?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, backwards-compatibility

Lets say I create a binary compatible update of my library `foo` from version `1.0.0` to `1.0.1`. Library `foo` is published via Maven.

Can I use this minor version update to bump at the same time the minor versions of the dependencies of `foo`? For example, version 1.0.0 was using `scalaVersion := "2.10.1"`. Can I change that to `scalaVersion := "2.10.3"` in foo 1.0.1, or will that cause trouble?

Assume that I use `foo` in another project as

```
"mygroup" %% "foo" % "1.0.+"
```

Comment: You should manage the version numbers in a parent pom.xml. That way the updated version is populated to all sub-modules. Is that something you are looking for?

Comment: How do you know that Scala 2.10.3 won't break your code? Or a project that depends on your code?

Comment: @chris.tian There is no parent pom. scala-library is independent from my library.

Comment: @hdave By convention, minor versions are binary compatible bug-fix only releases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several considerations involved, but generally yes, you can change the versions of dependencies if they are binary compatible.  The Scala team aims for 2.10.x releases to be binary compatible.  You can compile against Scala 2.10.1 and use 2.10.3 at runtime.

You can generally do the reverse for the Scala library as long as you use methods and types that are present in both.  Most libraries aren't concerned with this direction, though.  Other caveats on binary compatibility:

- Different libraries have different policies on what version bumps mean.
- Libraries may or may not have automation to check binary compatibility.
- Automation like [MiMa](https://github.com/typesafehub/migration-manager/wiki/Sbt-plugin) (used by Scala) does not catch all kinds of incompatibilities.  For example, MiMa only catches "syntactic" incompatibilities (ones that throw `LinkageError`s at runtime).
- Binary compatibility does not imply source compatibility.

It is not generally recommended to use dynamic revisions like "1.0.+", however.  They make reproducing builds harder as well as affecting resolution speed.

Comment: I am surprised that you recommend not using `+` versions. I have come to like them a lot. It allows me to publish a bug fix release and any new project can take advantage of them automatically. Kind of related to my question: If two dependencies A and B of my project depend themselves on C in two different minor versions, e.g. `1.0.0` and `1.0.1`, I think I end up having both `1.0.0` and `1.0.1` in `lib_managed`, or will sbt automatically fall back to `1.0.1`? This was for me the motivation of using `1.0.+`.

Comment: On lib_managed, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/21368201.  Ivy will resolve two different versions to one.  The default strategy in Ivy is to use the latest version, so 1.0.1 would be picked over 1.0.0.

Comment: On dynamic revisions, they make reproducibility harder.  You can do it, but it requires more work and in the end you really aren't using dynamic revisions anymore.  Note that they are not recommended by Gradle or Maven either.

Answer (score 2):

Generally modern software follows [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/)

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> ```
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
> ```

So `"2.10.3"` is to be compatible with any `"2.10.x"` version.

Usually we should not care about `.PATCH` part, except for cases when a bug affecting our code was fixed. And I guess that is the case.